# Replace ids in column with text in cell adjacent to another column with same ids (Excel/VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to replace all ids in a column with the adjacent value of the same id in an another column. The orders of the ids in both columns are the same but not on the same row.

This is what my table looks like:

```
| id |   | id | text_value |
|----|---|----|------------|
|    |   | 1  | John       |
|    |   | 2  | Mary       |
|    |   | 3  | Andy       |
| 1  |   | 4  | Susan      |
|    |   | 5  | Salomon    |
| 2  |   | 6  | Shana      |
| 3  |   | 7  | Kevin      |
|    |   | 8  | Marc       |
```

This what I want:

```
|   id   |   | id | text_value |
|--------|---|----|------------|
|        |   | 1  | John       |
|        |   | 2  | Mary       |
|        |   | 3  | Andy       |
|  John  |   | 4  | Susan      |
|        |   | 5  | Salomon    |
|  Mary  |   | 6  | Shana      |
|  Andy  |   | 7  | Kevin      |
|        |   | 8  | Marc       |
```

Is there a way to do this with VBA or an Excel function?

I use Excel for Mac v15.40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you data ara in column A to D and start from row 2

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        cell.Value = Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Find(WHAT:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm getting
'Runtime error 91':
Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: which line is throwing it?

Comment: The fourth line in the code you posted 
"cell.Value ="

Comment: is it possible an Id in column A isn't in column C?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it! It works perfectly, thank you so much! I'm very grateful.